# Diagram created with JsPlumb - what are alternatives for mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, diagram, jsplumb

I like [jsPlumb](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html) to display simple diagram.

But one problem for us is that jsPlumb does not work very well with mobile device. For example, when I tried to move one of textarea in mobile device, it does not let you do that like it does in PC. So my question: Is there any alternative or similar package we can use for mobile devices. Perhaps, some package with jquery mobile? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking it's not jsPlumb that doesn't play well, but the underlying library, which I suppose is jQuery in this case.  jsPlumb just does what its told as far as drag events are concerned: if you use it YUI dragging works on touch devices, for example.  But I realise jQuery has more users than YUI so touch support is something I am intending to look at in a future release.

Comment: I've not had much joy with jsPlumb. I found that it had odd interactions between the jQuery and its own code. I also don't like the odd mixture of HTML and JS required to get anywhere.